# Using Javascript to divide by 2 until i reach 1

Tags: javascript, math, counter, division, floor

I am trying to take a parameter called value and create a function that divides it by 2 and then increments a counter. When value reaches 1 I want to return the counter displaying how many times value was divided by 2 before reaching 1. so far i have

```
var count = 0;

function binary_seq(value) {
    while(value > 1) {
    Math.floor(value/2);
    count++;
    if (value == 1) {
        return count;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should store the result from Math.floor somewhere ;) And by return "count" you will return the string "count" not the variable

Comment: Yep you've effectively made a `while true`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```js
function binary_seq(value) {
    var count = 0;
    while(value > 1) {
        value = Math.floor(value/2); // Update the value of `value`
        count++;
    }
    return count; // Return the value of count
}

document.write(binary_seq(1024))
```

Also you do not need to have `count` defined outside of the function scope

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to compute the base 2 logarithm in javascript. Maybe it's part of a challenge or homework, but someone has to be the buzz killington mentioning the standard & easy way of solving this and that someone is me today.

```
Math.ceil(Math.log2(n)+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function binary_seq(value) {
    var count = 0;
    while(value >= 1) {
        value /= 2;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: you should store the result from Math.floor in value or the while loop won't work

Comment: You're dividing by the wrong number. `/=` should just be `=`. If `value` is initially 6 you end up with `value = value / Math.floor(6/2)` which is `value = 2` when it should be `value = 3`.

Comment: You know what you guys can do right?  You can go suck a....wait hold up....You can actually edit my answer and make a suggestion and do something constructive.  It helps me and the end user.  A lot of times I am busy working on projects and doing my best to help others in the mean time.  If you have a better answer you can surely post it.  But I doubt you would want to feel the heat that you give to others.